# How to ask for help if i know that the answers are (more or less) opinion based, but still helpfull?

Tags: support

I am a programmer, if i get stuck, most of the time the question/answer is easy and already to find here (ie. stackoverflow)

But sometimes there are questions, like 'shall I go right or left' (name a variable like something or not, use a '_' as starting char for a func name, or so)

The point is, I *want to ask for other opinions* to compleete my picture (this is a basic thing in human kind - I think)

Probably I get only 'go left' or something like 'You have overseen the pit fall, if you go right, you will get stuck')

I understand (and accept fully) why 'plain' opinion based questions are not ok, and not wanted here - like "what is the best IDE/OS/country" ore like

On the other hand - sometimes I want to ask something like 'how would you do that?'

Is there a way/cahnce to ask for others experience, even if it is an other(s)  opinion?

Comment: Use one of the many thousands of sites outside of the SE network to which programmers go to ask questions of each other.